# Would a question about the benefits of a masters degree be appropriate?

Tags: discussion

I wanted to ask a question about the objective benefits of a masters degree, but I couldn't decide if it would be appropriate. In short, the question would ask about the benefits (and negatives) of a masters degree after a number of years in industry, having worked on projects covering part of the space covered by the degree course.

My gut feeling is it would be too subjective, but I thought I'd ask in meta first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - as mentioned in [the Help Center's on-topic page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), questions about career and education are off-topic here.